# While installing it's taking too much time

Tags: xubuntu

i am installing ubuntu in my lenovo laptop . Once i complete language selection step click next taking me to update and other software page. I am waiting more than half an hour hour since i have given continue still its not moving to next page why [image][image]
Stdin type writter some erroe  are the happening before the ubuntu language setup screen coming what cause this issue. Sorry for my poor English

Comment: slow reading speed of the bootable USB/CD combined with a slow HDD probably?

Comment: Will it work if it takes too much time too install?

Comment: it can be a conflict with something other too, blocking in a loop (but i'm not at all an expert of the BIOS or something like that)

Comment: Before it come to ubuntu setup page it was printing stadin no type writter continously with blinking screen

Comment: edit and add this information to your question, it will help more other members

Comment: Okay i will do that wait

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you installing?  Which model of Lenovo laptop; not the marketing model (like 'ThinkPad R40') but the model number on the serial number plate on the underside?  How much memory does it have? What is the model of hard drive? Please click on https://askubuntu.com/posts/1054217/edit and add that information to your original post.